# How to fully justify tabular columns

Tags: tables, spacing

I would like a `tabular` environment with fully justified columns.  I my best guess of how to make this happen is to use a `tabularx` environment (so the tabular knows how wide to be) and then put `\hilll` (for some appropriate repetition of the letter `l`) between all adjacent columns.  However, that didn't work.  See the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before.

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l@{\hfill}c@{\hfill}r}
 On the LEFT & In the middle & On the RIGHT
\end{tabularx}

Text between. Text between. Text between. Text between. Text between. Text between. Text between.

\def\magicNumber{50pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcr}
 On the LEFT & \hspace*{\magicNumber} In the middle \hspace*{\magicNumber} & On the RIGHT
\end{tabularx}

Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first `tabularx` environment is my failed attempt.  The second `tabularx` environment is typeset (approximately) correct but is a hack using magic numbers.

### Question:

How can one properly use infinite glues (like `\hfill`) to specify the space between `tabularx` columns?  More generally, how can one obtain a `tabular` environment with fully justified columns?

Comment: I am not sure what you are after. The `X` column of `tabularx`?

Comment: @Johannes_B No. An `X` column is syntactic sugar for `p{<some value>}`, which specifies how wide the column in question should be.  I want to modify the space _between_ columns.

Comment: In general, `\tabcolsep` is the length that indicates buffer space around column data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) only works when you use an `X`-column. What you're interested in is probably setting `\extracolsep{\fill}`, as suggested in [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before.

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr@{}}
  On the LEFT & In the MIDDLE & On the RIGHT
\end{tabular*}

Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after.

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr@{}}
  On the LEFT & In the very MIDDLE & On the RIGHT
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the above doesn't represent "fully justified" columns. For that you could use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before.

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  On the LEFT & In the MIDDLE & On the RIGHT
\end{tabularx}

Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after. Text after.

\end{document}
```

If needed, you can modify the justification for the columns using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array).

Comment: Very good.  Your first suggestion using `\extracolsep{\fill}` is closer to what I really want.  This command sets the space between all pairs (of adjacent) columns.  Is there a way to set different values between different pairs (of adjacent) columns?

Comment: @TysonWilliams: You could still use `@{\hspace{<len>}}` to inserts a specific `<len>` between columns. However, when using `\@extracolsep{\fill}` and `@{\hspace{<len>}` both will be used.

Comment: But `@{\hspace{\fill}}` doesn't work.  Why not?

Comment: @TysonWilliams: I don't really know...

Comment: Ah, I figure out a good workaround.  As stated [here](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_69.html), "An `\extracolsep{wd}` command in an `@`-expression causes an extra space of width `wd` to appear to the left of all subsequent columns, until countermanded by another `\extracolsep` command." Thus, multiple uses of `\extracolsep{wd}` with varied `wd` parameters achieves my desired behavior.